# Invoking VBA code in MS Access from a C#.NET application

Tags: c#, .net, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a C#.NET desktop application that automates the execution of several different data processing jobs according to a fixed schedule. The C#.NET application uses the System.Diagnostics.Process class to invoke other .NET applications, batch files, and SAS jobs. I would also like to use it to automate running some MS Access reports, which are created using VBA in an Access 2010 database.

My question - how can I use my C#.NET program to trigger the execution of a VBA function (or Procedure) that resides in an Access database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check this out:

[How to automate Microsoft Access by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317114)